# What is the difference between SQLITE_THREADSAFE = 1 vs = 2 and why don't they allow sharing a same connection in multiple threads?

Tags: c++, multithreading, sqlite, qt, file-descriptor

From [SQLite compile time options](https://www.sqlite.org/compile.html#_options_to_set_default_parameter_values):

> ... SQLITE_THREADSAFE=1 sets the default threading mode to **Serialized**. SQLITE_THREADSAFE=2 sets the default threading mode to **Multi-threaded** ...

It further [states](https://www.sqlite.org/threadsafe.html):

> **Multi-thread**. In this mode, SQLite can be safely used by multiple
> threads provided that no single database connection is used
> simultaneously in two or more threads.
>
> **Serialized**. In serialized mode, SQLite can be safely used by multiple
> threads with no restriction.

1. It's not clear what is the use of "Multi-thread" (=2), if "Serialized" (=1) is capable of doing it without restrictions. The literal meanings of these 2 quoted terms are also not very clear.
2. Is the single DB connection in multiple threads not allowed for =2 option or =1 as well? Is that an undefined behaviour if used?

The reason for the second question is that, I have a requirement where several DB files are opened at the same time. They are being read in worker thread and written in a single DB thread. If I create 2 connections for each DB file, then soon the file descriptor limit can get exhausted for an OS.

Though we haven't faced any major problem, recently we came across a situation where the SQLite was accessed simultaneously from both the worker and DB threads. A long delay of 20 sec blocked the worker thread. This issue reproduces consistently.
This lead me to believe that, threading could be an issue. In my setup, the default =1 (Serialized) option is set at the compile time.

---

**Clarifications**:

- **Environment**: Using Qt/C++. For threading we use `QThread`s. IMO, this may not impact this behaviour
- **Threading**: There is a main thread, "database" thread and 4 worker threads. Every user sits on a particular worker thread for its socket connection. However their DBs are always on the common "database" thread
- **DB connections**: There can be hundreds of different DBs opened at a time depending on number of users connected to server. Since every OS has a limit of how many files can be opened at a time, I use 1 connection per DB file.
- **Connection sharing**: Every user's DB connection is shared between its worker thread for reading (`SELECT`) and the common DB thread for writing (`INSERT/DELETE/UPDATE`). I assumed that for `=1`, the connection can *probably* be shared.
- **Suspicion**: There is 1 table which has 10k+ rows and it also contains huge data in its columns. Total DB size goes upto 300-400 MBs mainly due to this. When a `SELECT` is invoked on this particular row based on its "id" field (30 character string). The first time, it takes upto 20 sec. The next time, it's few milliseconds

Don't remove the C++ tag.

Comment: This is not a C++ question, it is an sqllite question.  Try asking on an SqlLite forum, this one is for C++ (language) questions mostly. And we need at least a minimum reproducible example in C++ (e.g. one that can compile in a online or local compiler so we can reproduce the issue)

Comment: @PepijnKramer, this question is related to the precompiled macro `SQLITE_THREADSAFE` which is for C/C++. Moreover I also compile sqlite.c etc along with my Qt code.

Comment: Yes but that macro is sqllite specific, it is not part of standard C++ or standard C++ library (https://en.cppreference.com/w/). So my point is to get an answer to this question you need ask at some place where people know the sqllite library.

Comment: See this [discussion](https://sqlite.org/threadsafe.html) in the SQLite docs. Your question is not very clear on point, but it seems like you need to investigate [WAL mode](https://sqlite.org/wal.html).

Comment: I have not looked at the source, but it _sounds like_  `SQLITE_THREADSAFE=1` uses a global mutex that prevents any two threads from concurrently entering any SQLite function, while `...=2` does something (IDK what) that is both more sophisticated, and more risky.

Comment: You are asking for two different things in your question: multi-threaded use of the sqlite library and read-write concurrency on the datbase file which may happen also in single threaded by two different processes. For better answering your question we need to have more precise details on your threading model and your read-write pattern.

Comment: @davidriod i use `=1` (viz "Serialised") option with 2 QThreads sharing the same [each] DB connection. One always reads and other always writes. Only 1 process (.exe) is involved. Let me know if any more detail missed in the question apart from this.

Comment: What is a QThread ? What is your programming environment ? We still need you read-write pattern per connection, why do you open 2 connection per DB file ? how many db file do you have and what are their purpose ? we need more clarification on that. You should edit your question with these informations so that next readers can get more value from this question and eventually from the associated answer.

Comment: @davidriod, earlier tags provided some info on environment, but they were removed. Now the tags are restored with more clarification in the question body. We have 1 table with 10k rows and for the first `SELECT`, it takes 20 sec. Later on it's faster. Let me know if more info is needed.

Answer (score 0):

Well I'm no SQLite expert, but the following sounds quite clear to me:

> **Multi-thread**. In this mode, SQLite can be safely used by multiple threads provided that *no single database connection is used simultaneously in two or more threads*.
>
> **Serialized**. In serialized mode, SQLite can be safely used by multiple threads with *no restriction*.

From my understanding this means:

If you use SQLITE_THREADSAFE=2 (multithreaded) you have to make sure that each thread uses its own database connection. Sharing a single database connecgtion amongst multiple threads isn't safe.

If you use SQLITE_THREADSAFE=1 (serialized) you can even safely reuse a single databse connection amongst multiple threads.

Comment: You are quoting and re-quoting whatever is already quoted in the question . We need more elaboration on those terms and their behaviour.